# I have Created a form to upload images, where i should display error message if i upload more than 3 images and should disable submit button

Tags: ajax, javascript

I have Created a form to upload images, where i should display error message if i upload more than 3 images and should disable submit button to delete already uploaded image if i want to upload more images

Comment: Is this form a form API form? Content type? Or what?

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps

Go to image field settings of you content type.

Then Go to Image Field Settings and select '3' for number of values for the image

[image]

That's it. When user reaches their upload limit (3) the submit button will be disappeared automatically. and display like follows.

[image]